# How to link all files in C ansi? Error with multiple definition

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, multiple-definition-error

Good morning

This is big problem for me to link all files (**main.c, myFunc.c, myFuncHeaders.h** and **MakeFile**).
Problem is *multiple definition* when I don't know what should I do with it. I used global variables `char board[3][3]`, `char board_checked[3][3]` and `int playersRound`. I know that global would be unnecessary and bad designed program, but I wanted try something new. Simple tic tac toe game

In one file(all in one), code works. Here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char board[3][3] = {{'_', '_', '_'},{'_', '_', '_'},{'_', '_', '_'} };
char board_checked[3][3] = {{'+', '+', '+'},{'+', '+', '+'},{'+', '+', '+'}};
int playersRound = 0;

// It shows board
void show_board(){
    char * space = "          ";
    puts("\tPlansza\n\t==================================");
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s|%d|", space, i);
    }
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("\t|%d|",i+1);
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%c  %s", board[i][j], space);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    puts("\t==================================\n");
}


// This function add a player's mark - 'X' or 'O' - to board
void add_mark(int *p, int player){
    // If it isn't reserved by other mark
    if(board_checked[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] != '-'){
        // x (p[1]) and y (p[0]) vectors are (1, 2, 3)
        if(1 <= p[0] && p[0] <= 3 && 1 <= p[1] && p[1] <= 3)
        {
            if(player == 1)
            {
                // Add to board 'X'
                board[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = 'O';
                // and unchecked at the same position 'board_checked'
                board_checked[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = '-';

            }
            else
            {
                // Add to board 'X'
                board[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = 'X';
                // and unchecked at the same position 'board_checked'
                board_checked[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = '-';
            }
            // If Everything is Okey go to next playersRound
            playersRound++;
        }
    }
    else
        // On start variable is position[2] = {0,0}; it's mean that I made exception
        if(!(0 == p[0] && 0 == p[1]))
        {
            puts("Nie podales poprawnych parametrow");
            sleep(2);
        }
}


// This function check every position where any mark have been added
int structure_check(int player){
    //return winner
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        // Check horizontal
        for(int level = 0; level < 3; level++)
            if(board[level][0] == board[level][1] && board[level][0] == board[level][2] && board[level][0] != '_')return player;
        // Check vertical
        for(int level = 0; level < 3; level++)
            if(board[0][level] == board[1][level] && board[0][level] == board[2][level] && board[0][level] != '_')return player;
        // Check diagonal left
        if(board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2] && board[0][0] != '_')return player;
        // Check diagonal right
        if(board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[2][0] == board[0][2] && board[0][2] != '_')return player;
    }
    // Draw - when no one of two players won
    return 0;
}



int main(char argc, char * argv[]){
    int player = 1;
    int position[2] = {0,0};
    int status = 0;



    show_board();


    while(playersRound < 10){
        // Short information
        if(player == 1) puts("Gracz 1:");
        else puts("Gracz 2:");
        // Get position
        printf("\tx:"); scanf("%d", &position[0]);
        printf("\ty:"); scanf("%d", &position[1]);
        // status game, win or draw
        status = structure_check(player);
        // Players movement in playersRounds
        if(playersRound%2 == 0) player = 1;
        else player = 2;
        // This add mark to board by player
        add_mark(position, player);
        // Clear console
        system("cls");
        // Show only board
        show_board();
        // To be sure it works
        status = structure_check(player);
        // It finish when someone won game
        if(status != 0) break;
    }

    if(player == 1)
        printf("Wygrywa gracz: 1 z  'O'");
    else
        printf("Wygrywa gracz: 2 z  'X'");
    puts("  ||| Gratulacje! |||");

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is here:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "myFunc.c"
#include "myFuncHeaders.h"



int main(char argc, char * argv[]){
    int player = 1;
    int position[2] = {0,0};
    int status = 0;
    
    

    show_board();
    

    while(playersRound < 10){
        // Short information
        if(player == 1) puts("Gracz 1:");
        else puts("Gracz 2:");
        // Get position
        printf("\tx:"); scanf("%d", &position[0]);
        printf("\ty:"); scanf("%d", &position[1]);
        // status game, win or draw
        status = structure_check(player);
        // Players movement in playersRounds
        if(playersRound%2 == 0) player = 1;
        else player = 2;
        // This add mark to board by player
        add_mark(position, player);
        // Clear console
        system("clear");
        // Show only board
        show_board();
        // To be sure it works
        status = structure_check(player);
        // It finish when someone won game
        if(status != 0) break;
    }

    if(player == 1)
        printf("Wygrywa gracz: 1 z  'O'");
    else
        printf("Wygrywa gracz: 2 z  'X'");
    puts("  ||| Gratulacje! |||");

    return 0;
}
```

**myFunc.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> // sleep() 
#include "myFuncHeaders.h"

char board[3][3] = {{'_', '_', '_'},{'_', '_', '_'},{'_', '_', '_'} };
char board_checked[3][3] = {{'+', '+', '+'},{'+', '+', '+'},{'+', '+', '+'}};
int playersRound = 0;

// It shows board 
void show_board(){
    char * space = "          ";
    puts("\tPlansza\n\t==================================");
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s|%d|", space, i);
    }
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("\t|%d|",i+1);
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%c  %s", board[i][j], space);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    puts("\t==================================\n");
}


// This function add a player's mark - 'X' or 'O' - to board
void add_mark(int *p, int player){
    // If it isn't reserved by other mark
    if(board_checked[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] != '-'){
        // x (p[1]) and y (p[0]) vectors are (1, 2, 3)
        if(1 <= p[0] && p[0] <= 3 && 1 <= p[1] && p[1] <= 3)
        {
            if(player == 1)
            {
                // Add to board 'X'
                board[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = 'O';
                // and unchecked at the same position 'board_checked'
                board_checked[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = '-';

            }
            else
            {
                // Add to board 'X'
                board[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = 'X';
                // and unchecked at the same position 'board_checked'
                board_checked[p[0]-1][p[1]-1] = '-';
            }
            // If Everything is Okey go to next playersRound
            playersRound++;
        }
    }
    else
        // On start variable is position[2] = {0,0}; it's mean that I made exception
        if(!(0 == p[0] && 0 == p[1]))
        {
            puts("Nie podales poprawnych parametrow");
            sleep(2);
        }
}


// This function check every position where any mark have been added
int structure_check(int player){
    //return winner
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        // Check horizontal
        for(int level = 0; level < 3; level++)
            if(board[level][0] == board[level][1] && board[level][0] == board[level][2] && board[level][0] != '_')return player;
        // Check vertical
        for(int level = 0; level < 3; level++)
            if(board[0][level] == board[1][level] && board[0][level] == board[2][level] && board[0][level] != '_')return player;
        // Check diagonal left
        if(board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2] && board[0][0] != '_')return player;
        // Check diagonal right
        if(board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[2][0] == board[0][2] && board[0][2] != '_')return player;
    }
    // Draw - when no one of two players won
    return 0;
}
```

**myFuncHeaders.h**

```
void show_board();
// This function add a player's mark - 'X' or 'O' - to board
void add_mark(int *p, int player);
// This function check every position where any mark have been added
int structure_check(int player);
```

**MakeFile**

```
main:               main.o myFunc.o
                    gcc -o main main.o myFunc.o

myFunc.o:           myFunc.c myFunc.o
                    gcc -c -o myFunc.o myFunc.c
```

**Output:**

```
*my foleder*
~/zadania_domowe/kolko_krzyzyk $ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
make: circular version myFunc.o <- myFunc.o lost.
gcc -c -o myFunc.o myFunc.c
gcc -o main main.o myFunc.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: myFunc.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `board'; main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: myFunc.o:(.data+0x10): multiple definition of `board_checked'; main.o:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: myFunc.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `playersRound'; main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: myFunc.o: in function `show_board':
myFunc.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `show_board'; main.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: myFunc.o: in function `add_mark':
myFunc.c:(.text+0xf5): multiple definition of `add_mark'; main.o:main.c:(.text+0xf5): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: myFunc.o: in function `structure_check':
myFunc.c:(.text+0x2a6): multiple definition of `structure_check'; main.o:main.c:(.text+0x2a6): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: main] Error 1
```

I try with `extern` global, put this globals into the `main()` and then send to the functions. I had more errors then I expected. If someone have link or source to the same problem I will be glad for this information.

Comment: don't `#include "myFunc.c"`. It gets added to the final executable by the linker (not the compiler).

Comment: Ok it works. I'm very happy and Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you `#include "myFunc.c"` in `main.c` so you include the implementations of functions `show_board`, `add_mark`, etc. in the `main.o` compiled object, and those functions are also included in the `myFunc.o` compiled object, result of compiling the same source file directly.  The linker, on seeing this, complaints, as it cannot know which function to use, and when you make a call to e.g. `add_mark` in `main` it doesn't know which one is to be called.

To solve your problem, you just need to take off the line

```
#include "myFunc.c"
```

and include also `myFuncHeaders.h` in the file `myFunc.h`, so you can check that the definitions given in the header file are compatible with the implementations you provide in the file `myFunc.c`.

There is also an error from `make` telling that you have included a  rule indicating that `myFunc.o` file depends on `myFunc.o` which is a circular dependence, and it is an error (make cannot be given dependency rules with loops, as it would never end if it had to allow them)  you need to change

```
myFunc.o: myFunc.c myFunc.o
    gcc -c -o myFunc.o myFunc.c
```

into

```
myFunc.o: myFunc.c myFuncHeaders.h
    gcc -c -o myFunc.o myFunc.c
```

and write a similar one for `main.o` (which has been taken by default with the internal make's version, you will see that make has called `cc` compiler, to compile `main.c` instead of `gcc`)

```
main.o: main.c myFuncHeaders.h
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c
```

The rule is to think that if you touch (edit) any of the files `main.c` or `myFuncHeaders.h` (this last because you have modified the interface to the functions defined in `myFunc.c`, then you need to create a new compilation of `main.c` to `main.o`, or the final executable will be inconsistent (and your program will crash).

Comment: Hello Louis.
Thank you so much for explaining the topic from the ground up. It helped me a lot. Thank you for the time you took on this.